# How to make MySQL know sequential query-induced ID?

Tags: mysql, numbers, row

In the following query "id1" and "id2" are unknown, no matter if I change them to "myTable.id1" or to "r1.id1" or to "r2.id1":

```
SELECT      @n:=@n+1 AS id1,myTable.originalID,myTable.name,myTable.place
FROM        (myTable, (SELECT @n:=0) r1)
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT @i:=@i+1 AS id2,originalID,name,place FROM (myTable, (SELECT @i:=0) r2) WHERE originalID!=12) secondTable
ON          id1=id2;
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THey are unknown because the only columns known in a query (as a general rule) are the ones in the `from` clause.  You are defining these in the `select` clause.  Try putting the variable stuff in subqueries, something like:

```
select *
from (select @n := @n + 1 AS id1, mt.originalID, mt.name, mt.place
      from myTable mt cross join
           (select @n := 0) const
    ) t1 left join
    (SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS id2, originalID, name, place
     FROM myTable cross join
          (SELECT @i:=0) r2
     WHERE originalID <> 12
    ) secondTable
    ON t1.id1 = secondtable.id2;
```

Comment: Great, this was very helpful, Gordon!